# Show truck navigation on Google Maps

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps:
Can they be used to show activity of an object moving from one location to another "Live"? What I'm thinking of is dynamically and regularly keep on hitting the server retrieving object's location and display that on map.

Answer (score 0):

'Mashups' can do this very successfully. Last year the [Whitehat Rally](http://www.whitehatrally.org/static/pages/index.html) ran a real-time overlay to display the location of all the cars in the rally on a Google map at 5 minute intervals.

(feel free to donate - **Whitehat Rally raised nearly £40,000 for children's charity Childline** last year, and hoping to beat that this year)